# Why does a file's Inode number change and nothing else?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode, file-metadata, tripwire

Today I noticed that tripwire thinks that some Apache configuration files *changed* yesterday. I know I did not make any changes to those files.

Looking at the info, it shows that only the Inode number changed:

```
  Property:            Expected                    Observed
  -------------        -----------                 -----------
  Object Type          Regular File                Regular File
  Device Number        2305                        2305
* Inode Number         5770048                     5771399
  Mode                 -rw-r--r--                  -rw-r--r--
  Num Links            1                           1
  UID                  root (0)                    root (0)
  GID                  root (0)                    root (0)
  Size                 1055                        1055
  Modify Time          Mon 09 Oct 2017 04:54:54 PM PDT
                                               Mon 09 Oct 2017 04:54:54 PM PDT
  Blocks               8                           8
  CRC32                BSW2x+                      BSW2x+
  MD5                  CqXESieHTV/33Ye6iuaHjk      CqXESieHTV/33Ye6iuaHjk
```

How could the Inode of a file change and nothing else?

Comment: The `ctime` would have changed too if the file was modified using the usual system calls.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes! However, it looks like tripwire only shows `mtime`. So it could be that `ctime` and `atime` changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
cp -p file file.new && mv file.new file
```

For example:

```
$ ls -li file
12289 -rw-r--r--    1 jeff jeff 0 Jun 13 14:24 file
$ cp -p file file.new && mv file.new file
$ ls -li file
12292 -rw-r--r--    1 jeff jeff 0 Jun 13 14:24 file
```

Another possibility would be that the file was restored from a backup system (and that backup system restored timestamps).

Another activity that would update the inode number and not touch the contents would be a `sed -i` command that made no changes, since `sed -i` use a temporary file for the results which is then renamed to the original at the end.

Comment: The only thing I've done which I can think of would possibly have had an impact is upgrade the OS (`apt-get dist-upgrade`). I don't see why they would have moved the file in this way, except that there could be a process which verified that a certain parameter was not used and that updated the files without changes inside the file since I would not have been using that parameter... An `sed` that would preserve the Inode info...

Comment: @Alexis, a noop `sed -i` command would do it, too (see the edit)

Comment: Ah! Got it! The tripwire test does not include `ctime` and `atime` which explains why it would not detect that those changed too. It would have helped to have that important point in your answer! :-)

Comment: I didn't have that information when I answered, so if you would like to add that as an edit, I'd accept it (if it's not approved before I see it).

Comment: Well, the output I show only includes a line for _Modify Time_. The other two times are not included. So it was there, just not obvious. :-)